# Для чего нужен Constraint name в mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Для чего нужен `Constraint name` при создании связи таблиц в mysql?
Пример:

```
Constraint name friends_ibfk_1
Constraint name friends_ibfk_2
Constraint name friends_ibfk_3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У каждого объекта в базе данных, включая внешние ключи таблиц, должно быть имя, необходимое для того, что бы в последствии можно было модифицировать данный объект. Если имя не указано, то mysql сам придумает некое имя.

Предложение `Constraint NAME` задает имя внешнего ключа явным образом. Задав имя ключа в последствии, если вы захотите его удалить, вы сможете это сделать с помощью `alter table Tab drop foreign key NAME`.

Так же ключевое слово constraint необходимо для некоторой совместимости со стандартами SQL. Например в mysql с помощью него так же можно объявить CHECK ограничение, которое по стандартам SQL должно накладывать ограничения на поле, например, что его значение должно быть больше нуля. Правда MySQL не поддерживает проверку таких ограничений, но синтаксис их создания за ошибку не считает, для совместимости с другими СУБД.

Answer (score 1):

Это ограничение внешнего ключа, позволяющее связать данные из одной или нескольких таблиц, например, чтобы нельзя было удалить данные из одной таблицы, без удаления связанных данных в другой или чтобы удаление/обновление в одной таблице приводило к каскадному удалению/обновлению данных в других таблицах. Это позволяет поддерживать согласованность базы данных, не допуская, чтобы появлялись ключи ссылающиеся на несуществующие записи.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы спрашиваете по причине, что эти constraints мешают Вам выполнять действия по импорту/экспорту данных, то их можно отключить на время выполенения скриптов:

`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` выключает

соответственно
`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;`
включает проверку внешних ключей.

Однако это небезопасно с точки зрения целостности данных. Обычно ошибка внешних ключей возникает, когда нарушен порядок вставки таблиц. Например, вставляется таблица городов, где внешний ключ указывает на страну (каждый город принадлежит какой-то стране), но при этом таблицы стран еще не существует.

Как я уже говорил, на свой страх и риск Вы можете отключить проверку ключей на время вставки данных. Но тогда есть вероятность получить "ничейные" данные. В случае с городами, Вы можете получить город, к. не принадлежит ни одной из стран.